# Extend boost::variant through macro

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, variant

Suppose I define `n` classes through macro expansion. I'd like to register each class and then generate, for `n = 2`, a boost::variant like:

```
// GeneratedClass_0 generated by macro
// GeneratedClass_1 generated by macro
boost::variant<GeneratedClass_0, GeneratedClass_1> v_class;
```

I saw that I can use this:

```
using namespace boost;
typedef mpl::vector< GeneratedClass_0 > DefaultTypes;
typedef mpl::push_front< DefaultTypes, GeneratedClass_1 >::type ExtendedTypes;
typedef boost::make_variant_over< ExtendedTypes >::type v_class;
```

However, `make_variant_over` is not supported in each compiler, even if I cannot see a list.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking... are you saying `make_variant_over` doesn't compile, or are you asking how build the `ExtendedTypes` sequence, or what?

Comment: I'm saying that `make_variant_over` is not a portable solution since it is not supported for all compilers. For this reason I need to build the boost::variant in a different way.